# Apple TV will not connect to my new Belkin wireless router?

Tags: appletv

I installed a new Belkin wireless N router and now my Apple TV wont connect to it??
Any quick fixes??
I may have entered a wrong password when asked to by AppleTV.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make it the same SSID and a different password? If so, it's probably caching the creds. Do a factory reset on the Apple TV

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).